# Folder structure for git repo

Tags: git

At present my file structure looks something like:

```
.git/
.fonts/
stuff/
code/
notes/
exe/
app/
res/
node_modules/
.gitignore
nodeserver.js
package.json
```

This is a git repo containing a node app, which I push both to bitbucket (for versioning and for safekeeping), and which I also [push to heroku in order to deploy the node app](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/git#deploying-code).

The "stuff" folder has useful bits and bobs that I need to keep, but it's stuff that isn't actually required by the node app.  Therefore it's pointless pushing that to heroku and increasing the size on heroku for no good reason.  (The same can be said for other folders like "notes", but I'm just singling out "stuff" as an example.)

So I'd like reorganise my repo so that the "stuff" folder is still pushed to origin, but is not pushed to heroku.  Is that possible?

Being simple myself, I'd like to keep things simple and easy to understand.  I've looked at git submodules and subtrees but they look pretty hellish for the ordinary user.

I had considered just putting "stuff" into the `.gitignore` (so that it is not pushed to anywhere), and then within "stuff" creating a completely independent repo that I push only to bitbucket, but this seems kludgy to me.  There may be a better way.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a script (shell-script, maven, Gradle, Jenkins-pipeline, etc.) that copies only what you need to a temporary folder and then push that folder to heroku.